# Firebase recycler adapter pagination

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Restaurant, FirebaseRestaurantViewHolder>
            (Restaurant.class, R.layout.restaurant_list_item, FirebaseRestaurantViewHolder.class, 
                mRestaurantReference)
```

I had like 1000 elements/objects in `mRestaurantReference`. I will definitely get performance issues if I use the above code so I have to paginate it. So how can I paginate data using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`?

Comment: Have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278544/how-to-paging-query-from-firebase-using-android-firebaseui)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paging query from Firebase using Android FirebaseUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278544/how-to-paging-query-from-firebase-using-android-firebaseui)