# How to paging query from Firebase using Android FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat project using Firebase Android SDK for the server. After 3 months, my application has many users and they chat with each other a lot. It takes a long time to load all of any chat list from Firebase. So now, I wonder that how to paging query from Firebase using Android SDK.

I researched this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) to find a query command for this problem but fail. I only query a number of the row from first or last. I could not query from random locate in Firebase. Example using `skip` and `take` key to query.

If you have any document about that. Please tell me.
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this demo [Firebase Paginator](https://github.com/natuanorg/FirebasePaginator) and it work for me. Although, it have some issues.

Answer (score 7):

Concepts like `skip()` or `take()` don't map well to the realtime world of the Firebase Database. That's why pagination will also be challenging to implement. Technically it is possible, but for a good user experience it's important you keep in mind that the data on a page may change while the user sees it.

Back to how you can implement pagination: the `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods take a optional second parameter, which is documented as (emphasis mine):

> ```
> public Query startAt (String value, String key)
> ```
>
> Create a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given value, using the given `orderBy` directive or priority as default, and additionally **only child nodes with a key greater than or equal to the given key**.

So if you for example have a list of items sorted by date, you can pass in the date **and key** of the last item on the previous page to get the next page. You'll have to request one extra item (often called the anchor item), but the overhead should be small.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I thought about this solution. However, It hard to make sure that I load 100 items per page.

Comment: hey this is a great answer, have been struggling to solve it and keep hitting dead ends, can you please add an example of database structure? Thanks